# Comparing one list to another and creating a subset list

Tags: python, list

What the code is supposed to do is to take two lists(list a and list b) of integers as inputs and returns a subset of the second list(list b)that are within on unit of an integer in the first list(list a). So far I have this:

```
def omssa(a,b):
new=[]
for x in b:
    boolean=True
    while(boolean==True):
        for char1 in a:
            if(b[x]== a[char1]):
                new.append(b[x])
                boolean=False
            elif(b[x]==(a[char1]+1)):
                new.append(b[x])
                boolean=False
            elif(b[x]==(a[char1]-1)):
                new.append(b[x])
                boolean=False
        boolean=False
return new
```

However I get a list index out of range error at line 7: if(b[x]== a[char1]):
Is there a way to check indexs as this function goes on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `for char1 in a`, `char1` is the actual value in the list, not an index. So you can't use `a[char1]`. See [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), or iterate using `range()` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If your lists does not contain the same int multiple time, you should use `set` objects instead of `list`. like :

```
def omssa(a,b):
    b2 = set(b)
    return b2.intersect(a)
```